# Sorting HEX color values into rainbow order using Android java or sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting, hex

I have amongst others a text field in my sqlite database that represents HEX color values, for example "92B01C". I populate a listview with a cursor like so:

```
data = database.query("threads", newfields, where_clause, null, null, null, "CAST(" + newfields[0] + " AS TEXT)" + " " + "COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
dataAdapter.changeCursor(data);
dataAdapter.getCursor().requery();
```

Where newfields[0] is the sqlite database hex color field.

My goal is to sort the listview by HEX colors in 'rainbow order', ie All the RED shades together then the GREEN shades etc. etc.

I'm guessing I will have to convert the String hex values to RGB values and then somehow apply this to the database query.

So my questions are:

1. Can such a db.query be made to sqlite or would I have to somehow do this outside of the query?
2. How to split the string hex value into RGB colors so that they can be sorted in rainbow order? I thought about using Collections.sort but then how would that be used in conjunction with the database.query?
3. If it cannot be achieved within the db.query how to apply any collections.sort to the listview after the sqlite database.query?

Any help would be great...

UPDATE

Thanks for all the suggestions, this is where i'm at:

I created a new db integer field "color_sortorder" which I will use for color sort order.

I loop the db HEX color string field and add it to an arraylist.

```
while (colorrawdata.isAfterLast() == false) {
    hexcoloritems.add(colorrawdata.getString(colorrawdata.getColumnIndex("colorref")));
    colorrawdata.moveToNext();
}
```

I then sort the arraylist using this Comparator:

```
class mycolorComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String strA, String strB) {

        float[] hsv1 = new float[3];
        float[] hsv2 = new float[3];

        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(strA, 16);
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(strB, 16);

        Color.colorToHSV(n1, hsv1);
        Color.colorToHSV(n2, hsv2);

        if ((int)hsv1[0] == (int)hsv2[0]) {
            return (int)hsv1[2] - (int)hsv2[2];
        }

        return (int)hsv1[0] - (int)hsv2[0];

    }
}
```

I then loop the arraylist to populate the new db color sort field.

```
for (int x = 0; x < hexcoloritems.size(); x++) {
    database.execSQL("UPDATE threads SET color_sortorder='" + x + "' WHERE colorref='" + hexcoloritems.get(x) + "';");
}
```

The result are promising but not quite correct. The listview of colors appear to be grouped but within the grouping of say Greens, the shades do not run from light to dark but instead are randomly sorted (but are correctly shades of green).

This is the resulting order (first 20 of 520)

```
Setting db color_sortorder to 0 where db colorref=FAFAFA
Setting db color_sortorder to 1 where db colorref=FAFAFA
Setting db color_sortorder to 2 where db colorref=000000
Setting db color_sortorder to 3 where db colorref=de605e
Setting db color_sortorder to 4 where db colorref=F2ACAC
Setting db color_sortorder to 5 where db colorref=C16363
Setting db color_sortorder to 6 where db colorref=FAFAFA
Setting db color_sortorder to 7 where db colorref=B61F1E
Setting db color_sortorder to 8 where db colorref=951A18
Setting db color_sortorder to 9 where db colorref=CC2523
Setting db color_sortorder to 10 where db colorref=ffd5d5
Setting db color_sortorder to 11 where db colorref=FFCECE
Setting db color_sortorder to 12 where db colorref=FFE1E1
Setting db color_sortorder to 13 where db colorref=FFD5D5
Setting db color_sortorder to 14 where db colorref=D64542
Setting db color_sortorder to 15 where db colorref=8E3230
Setting db color_sortorder to 16 where db colorref=D6403D
Setting db color_sortorder to 17 where db colorref=DB3D38
Setting db color_sortorder to 18 where db colorref=FFC1BF
Setting db color_sortorder to 19 where db colorref=D58582
```

The problem, I guess, is with the Comparator, can anyone give me some insight into what the problem is with it?

Comment: Sorting by RGB values will not give you rainbow order. You may get better results if the color values are represented in the HSL or HSV system.

Comment: A 6-digit hex string can be converted to an integer with `n = Integer.parseInt(str,16)`.  In `android.graphics.Color`, there's a static method `colorToHSV` which would convert `n` to HSV values, and then I think you'd sort on the H (Hue).  Sorry, but I don't know how to integrate all this with database functionality.

Comment: Stored function could be used to apply the transformation from HEX to HSV color model; but it would probably not perform well for large number of rows. And I'm not sure sqllite even supports stored functions... my guess the "lite" part in the name is there for a reason.

Comment: Put **another field** in your table, let's say `colorID`: let it be an integer and assign it a progressive number for the colors in the right sequence you want. Then sort your colors by **this** field. Easy.

Comment: Thank you for this information. While the result might not be ideal for your purpose the latest version of the question pretty much answers the original and might be sufficient in most similar cases (like mine). It's worth posting it as an answer. Adding an id column to the table may seem an obvious solution and perhaps is sufficient for some scenarios. But if that data is not carrying any information other than how to present it to the user I would not include it in the database as it could introduce all sorts of new problems e.g. for user defined colors or exchanging colors among databases.